# How to get speech to text to work in google docs in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, microphone, google-drive, voice-recognition

I can't get speech to text to work on google docs.
I have the voice to code program Serenade for visual studio code and chrome installed and it works.
I use Ubuntu 20.04.

What I did: I went to google docs made a new document went to tools-> speech to text.
pressed the microphone.
It gives me an error, it says that I'm not online and it will be working when I'm online again. It doesn't make sense because I am online though. What to do?
My wrist are sore from writing I could really need some relief. thanks :)

Comment: What does this have to do with Ubuntu?

Comment: Dose it has anything to do with ubuntu good question. Do you think its a bug at google? Im running ubuntu on my computer. I was thinking the problem properly was there. since google's stuff use to work. it can also be the installation of chrome? I don't know